# Restored database has different record count than dumped database

Tags: mongodb, restore

I am a DBA working for a small company. Our first business project is eBook. My supervisor ask me to study and deploy MongoDB as the primary DB for the whole project. Our project is still in the development stage.

Last night, we encountered a serious problem. My supervisor asked me to dump data from database in Server A, then restore to Server B.

This is my command:

```
Server A
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 -d puppy -o /
tar -cpf /puppy.tar /puppy/

Server B
scp root@hostname:/puppy.tar /
cd /
tar -xf puppy.tar
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 -d puppy --directoryperdb /puppy/ --drop
```

After these actions, I found the record count of database “puppy” in Server B did not match the number of Server A. After several trials and use of the command:

```
use puppy; db.dropDatabase();mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 -d puppy --directoryperdb /puppy/ --drop
```

It still did not work.

And after that, I tried to restore Server A from its own DB dump file and a disaster happened. Record number in Server A is the same number in Server B! Because this is a regular action that I've done before, and never encountered such a big problem, it shocks me and my supervisor.

We took a long time to fix this problem. But my supervisor asked me to find reason, or I’ll be fired! This is my worst nightmare! Can anyone give me a clue?

Thank for your help.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is? Edit your question: remove irrelevant history and tell us exactly what do you want to do.

Comment: hello,my original goal is to dump A mongodb to B mongodb. I hope to know why "mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 -d puppy --directoryperdb /puppy/ --drop" cannot be successfully restore to B. Another thing is why I use the dump files from A server to restore to A server，then all data in A become all data in B.

Comment: hello,is that possible that dump file is differ from its original DB data?

Comment: You don't give us much to work. What does it mean "record number did not match". It was bigger, smaller? It happened to every collection, or only subset of collections. Did you check timestamps of inconsistent documents. Did you create checksums for backup and can you confirm that data you restored is the one that should be restored. Is it possible that original data has been modified after dump. Did you check output of `mongodump` when you performed backup?